# CARTO Postgres frequency table by year

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to querying PostgresSQL and appreciate your help. I have a large table with dates [like such for 2019](https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20permitissuedate%20FROM%20permits%20WHERE%20date_part(%27year%27,%20permitissuedate)%20=%202019):

```
https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT permitissuedate FROM permits WHERE date_part('year', permitissuedate) = 2019
```

I simply would like a frequency table of records by year, but just can't figure out if my errors are related to Postgres in general or CARTO, the owner of the API. My understanding is that I need to convert the timestamp to year with `date_trunc`, count these years, and then `group_by` the converted year field. Below is one example of my mess. Any help would be appreciated.

```
https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT permitissuedate count(date_trunc('year', permitissuedate)) from PERMITS GROUP BY date_trunc('year', permitissuedate))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw query:

```sql
SELECT extract(year from permitissuedate) as year, count(*) 
from PERMITS 
GROUP BY year order by year;
```

The URL:

```
https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT extract(year from permitissuedate) as year, count(*) from PERMITS GROUP BY year order by year
```

See the [demo](https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20extract(year%20from%20permitissuedate)%20as%20year,%20count(*)%20from%20PERMITS%20GROUP%20BY%20year%20order%20by%20year).

**Edit**

- In this case I prefer `extract(year from permitissuedate)` over `date_trunc` only because it returns a number rather than a timestamp;
- `count(1)` is like `count(*)`, count ones - the number of records in each group. You can use any of them;
- `GROUP BY 1` is short for "group by the first select expression" i.e. `GROUP BY extract(year from permitissuedate)`;
- `order by 1` is similar,  "order by the first select expression".

You can btw `ORDER BY year` as `year` is the alias of `extract(year from permitissuedate)`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain a couple things? Why use `extract` over `date_trunc`? What is the `1` doing in `count`? How does this then relate to the `group_by` and `order`.

Comment: Thanks @Stefanov.sm - I really appreciate your help!